# Change Background Color from Code in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, background

I have this in my .xaml Code with a background defined:

```
<Window x:Class="BDE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BDE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BDE" Height="768" Width="1024"
        Background="#FF1B1534"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txt_identifikationsnummer}"
        WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
```

How can i acces the Background Property in the .cs code to change it in a function

Comment: control.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#082049");

Comment: I don't have control.Background. Just getting Control.BackgroundProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *.cs code*, You mean code behind of the `Window`, then you can change `Background` color for example inside the constructor of the `MainWindow`, like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Or in any other method of the MainWindow class.

Comment: Why do you think you can not use `this` outside the constructor?

Comment: That's correct, it's not necessary to reference by the name of the object, as long as `this` is an object we want to reference.

Comment: You write that the property can be changed inside the constructor. That is misleading. The property can be changed in any method of the MainWindow class.